What would be a good way to connect parts that would be replaced on a training model?
I'm trying to work on a training model for neurosurgery. Residents will be operating on the posterior part of the model, and it needs to be replaced after each training session. While the anterior part doesn't need replacing and should be secured on the table.
I've made little holes and protrusions that would ensure correctly aligned placement, but I can't figure out a good way to have them both connect securely since the residents will be using high-speed drills to remove "bone" and Kerrison rongeur(a handheld device that "bites" bone and removes it when you pull back). 
Of course, a screw can be placed through the back into the front side, but that would both reduce the realistic look of the model, and the anterior part would eventually loosen.
Of course, I can make this into a two-step model and first make residents place pedicular screws, both training them in that aspect, securing the vertebrae, and then doing the bone removal surgery. 
Here is what I have so far:  Note that screw entry points and insertion points are actually in alignment.
